# Отладка проекта Laravel в NetBeans не работает

Tags: laravel, отладка, netbeans

- стоит Xampp 7.1.12 / PHP 7.1.12.
- скачал соответствующую версию xDebuger php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll
- положил в папку C:\xampp\php\ext
- отредактировал php.ini следующим образом:

  output_buffering = Off

  [XDebug]

  zend_extension="c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll"

  xdebug.remote_autostart=1

  xdebug.default_enable=1

  xdebug.remote_port=9000

  xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"

  xdebug.remote_connect_back=1

  xdebug.remote_enable=1

  xdebug.idkey="netbeans-xdebug"
- включил Debuge mode в config/app.php:  'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)
- перезапустил Apache
- в настройках NetBeans указал порт 9000 и ID сессии netbeans-xdebug
- папка проекта лежит в "C:\xampp\htdocs"

Включаю отладку (или просто выбираю 'Выполнение') и NetBeans открывает в браузере страницу localhost/dashboard/, а не мой проект.

Я недавно познакомился с Laravel, поэтому мог упустить что-то элементарное.
Прошу помочь, убил день на это, пробовал и с PHPStorm, там тоже не вышло, но там другая беда.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось всё просто:

- открыть проект
- открыть его свойства (правый клик на проекте - свойства)
- перейти на вкладку 'Выполнить настройку'
- указать правильный URL адрес проекта